# Choose closest object to mouse click

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to find closest object to mouse click position.

Is that possible ?

My objects are very small, like DOT. So i could not select them, i thought may be i can find closest object to mouse click position.

Is there any way to find it ?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var circle, isDown, origX, origY;

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
      isDown = true;
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
      origX = pointer.x;
      origY = pointer.y;
      circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: pointer.x,
        top: pointer.y,
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'red',
        selectable: false,
        originX: 'center', originY: 'center',
      });
      canvas.add(circle);
      canvas.renderAll();
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
      isDown = false;
    });
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but in the case where the library does not support such feature, you can always use a [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or similar data structures to check for closest objects.

Comment: I would suggest a quick fix of creating a larger object with padding so it is selectable although the element is small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the closest object from `canvas._object`.
Here on `mouse:move` event.

```
  for ( i = 0; i < canvas._objects.length; i++){
    if(Math.pow(canvas._objects[i].left - origX,2) + Math.pow(canvas._objects[i].top - origY,2) < minLength){
       minObj = canvas._objects[i];
       minLength = Math.pow(canvas._objects[i].left - origX,2) + Math.pow(canvas._objects[i].top - origY,2);
    }
  }
```

FULL CODE Snippet

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { selection: false });

var circle, isDown, origX, origY;

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
      isDown = true;
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
      origX = pointer.x;
      origY = pointer.y;
      circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: pointer.x,
        top: pointer.y,
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'red',
        selectable: false,
        originX: 'center', originY: 'center',
      });
      canvas.add(circle);
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
      var minLength = 10000000;
      var minObj = null;
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
      origX = pointer.x;
      origY = pointer.y;
      for ( i = 0; i < canvas._objects.length; i++){
        if(Math.pow(canvas._objects[i].left - origX,2) + Math.pow(canvas._objects[i].top - origY,2) < minLength){
           minObj = canvas._objects[i];
           minLength = Math.pow(canvas._objects[i].left - origX,2) + Math.pow(canvas._objects[i].top - origY,2);
        }
      }
      for ( i = 0; i < canvas._objects.length; i++){
        if(canvas._objects[i] == minObj){
           canvas._objects[i].set({fill: 'blue'});
        }else{
           canvas._objects[i].set({fill: 'red'});
        }
      }
      canvas.renderAll();
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
      isDown = false;
    });
      canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'red',
        selectable: false,
        originX: 'center', originY: 'center',
      }));
      canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'red',
        selectable: false,
        originX: 'center', originY: 'center',
      }));
      canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is O(n) complexity, i thought may be there is a better case of this.